# vb.net - combobox error:'Cannot bind to the new value member. Parameter name: value'

Tags: vb.net, combobox, dataset

I actually have three combobox bind to diffrent table. and I got such the error in my title. Bellow are my codes:

```
myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT (FirstName +' '+ LastName) AS FullName FROM tblVisitor", myConnection)
   myAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
   myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "tblVisitor")
   cboVisitor.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0)
   cboVisitor.DisplayMember = "FullName"
   cboVisitor.ValueMember = "VisitorID"

   'my another combobox
   myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT BookCode FROM tblBook", myConnection)
   myAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
   myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "tblBook")
   cboBookCode.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(1)
   cboBookCode.DisplayMember = "BookCode"
   cboBookCode.ValueMember = "BookCode"  'where BookCode is the pk-column of the tblBook

   'my another combobox
   myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT (FirstName +' '+ LastName) AS StaffFullName FROM tblStaff", myConnection)
   myAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
   myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "tblStaff")
   cboStaff.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(2)
   cboStaff.DisplayMember = "StaffFullName"
   cboStaff.ValueMember = "StaffID"
```

Through this code, i got only the first comboboxthat display the query result, but the other two do not, and display the message 'Cannot bind to the new value member. Parameter name: value'. Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT (FirstName +' '+ LastName) AS FullName FROM tblVisitor;SELECT BookCode FROM tblBook;SELECT (FirstName +' '+ LastName) AS StaffFullName FROM tblStaff", myConnection)
   myAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
   myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet)

   cboVisitor.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0)
   cboVisitor.DisplayMember = "FullName"
   cboVisitor.ValueMember = "VisitorID"

   'my another combobox
   cboBookCode.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(1)
   cboBookCode.DisplayMember = "BookCode"
   cboBookCode.ValueMember = "BookCode"  'where BookCode is the pk-column of the tblBook

   'my another combobox
   cboStaff.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(2)
   cboStaff.DisplayMember = "StaffFullName"
   cboStaff.ValueMember = "StaffID"
```

You were confusing things by calling `.Fill()` multiple times for the same dataset.  This will also perform better by only making one round-trip to the database.

Comment: Oh - @Vivek spotted it better.  But I still think you should _also_ make the changes I suggested here, to avoid unneeded extra trips to the db.

Comment: guy, it still does not work, it does display the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

VisitorID and StaffID are not part of the Select statements.

Comment: guy, it still does not work, it does display the same error message

Answer (score 0):

The error your receiving " *...display the message 'Cannot bind to the new value member. Parameter name: value'.* " is probably not due to the .Net code rather the SQL statement you are using. I had a simlar problem where I was only select only the column of the value I needed. in example:

`Select FullName from tblVisitor;`

When you do this you are only selecting FullName the ID isn't in your dataset.
So you Would need to call:

`Select * from tblVisitor;`

Then this code should work to display your memnbers:

`cboVisitor.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0)
  cboVisitor.DisplayMember = "FullName"
  cboVisitor.ValueMember = "VisitorID"`

hope this helps